# How to assign the value to array of object correctly?

Tags: java, arrays

I don't know why after I'm running the code, array `scoreMatrix` always put the last assignment to the whole array.

```
        String input, seq="ACGT";
        PairScore[] scoreMatrix = new PairScore[16];
        for(int x = 0; x<16 ; x++){
            scoreMatrix[x] = new PairScore();
        }
        Scanner user_input = new Scanner( System.in );
        for(int i = 0; i <4;i++){
            input=user_input.nextLine();
            String[] inputSplite = input.split("\\s+");
            for(int j=0; j<4;j++){
                scoreTable[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(inputSplite[j]); 
            }
        }
        for(int x = 0; x<4 ; x++){
            for(int y=0; y<4; y++){
                scoreMatrix[x*4 +y].fString = Character.toString(seq.charAt(x));
                scoreMatrix[x*4 +y].sString = Character.toString(seq.charAt(y));
                scoreMatrix[x*4 +y].score = scoreTable[x][y];
            }
        }// Fix the score pair problems;
        for(int x1 = 0; x1<4 ; x1++){
            for(int y1=0; y1<4; y1++){
                System.out.println(scoreMatrix[x1*4 +y1].fString+scoreMatrix[x1*4 +y1].sString+scoreMatrix[x1*4 +y1].score);
            }
        }
```

Here is the code for the class PairScore

```
public class PairScore {
public static String fString;
public static String sString;
public static int score;
```

}

When I input

```
1 -1 -1 -1
-1 1 -1 -1
-1 -1 1 -1
-1 -1 -1 1
```

I got the following result:

```
TT1TT1TT1TT1.....TT1
```

but I expect to get the below result from the code:

```
AA1AC-1AG-1AT-1CA-1CC1...TT1
```

Why does it take the value TT1 and assign it to the rest of the array?

Comment: you `score` is static, this affects how it gets modified everywhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure the members of `PairScore` (`fString`, `sString` and `score`) are not static.

If they are static, all instances of the `PairScore` class will share a single value for these three members, so you'll only see the last value that was assigned to those variables.

Comment: Why static is meter here?

Comment: @Makara a static variable means a single variable for all instances of the class, so all PairScore objects would use this single variable.